# google chart All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm drowing a bar chart with dynamic data.
I couldn't figure out why do i still get the data type error.
This is my function:

```
function drawBasic(object,id,title) {

var array = ['publisher','price','date'];
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
     if(array[j] == 'publisher'){
        data.addColumn('string', array[j]);
     } else if (array[j] == 'revenue'){
        data.addColumn('number', array[j]);
     } else if(array[j] == 'date'){
        data.addColumn('date', 'X');
     }
}

$.each(object,function (key,val) {
    var temp = [];
    var outterArray = [];
    var day = new Date(key);
    for(var y = 0; y < val.length; y++){

        for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
             if(array[x] =='publisher'){
                    temp.push(val[y][array[x]]);
             } else if(array[x] != 'date' && array[x] !='publisher'){
                    temp.push(parseObjToNum(val[y][array[x]]));
             }
        }
        temp.push(day);
        outterArray.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
    data.addRows(outterArray);
});

var options = {
    title: title,
    hAxis: {
        "format": "y-MM-d"
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(id));
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits: true});
formatter.format(data, 1, 2, 3);
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The column is structured as: publisher type string, price type number and X type date.

Row single data example:

> ['josh the great',12, Tue Sep 20 2016 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)]

The data is ordered according to the column.

I'm aiming to present for each date the set of publishers and their price.
I don't mind representing it in a different chart but i don't think it's the problem.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each chart type has a specific [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format)

for Bar Charts, and most others, a `'date'` column is only valid as the first column
it cannot be a *series* column -- which can only be numbers

to display the date in the chart, recommend using a [Column Role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)
using either `'annotation'` or `'tooltip'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Publisher'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Price'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['josh the great', 12, 'Tue Sep 20 2016 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)'],
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```